# Meaning of "scale"

Tags: meaning

I read the sentence: "to globalize we need to scale our leadership" during a presentation of a big company. Then they talked about how leaders have to be accountable and deliver on their commitments. I really don't know what "scale" means in the sentence. I've checked some dictionaries but it's still not clear.

Comment: scale [up or down] a company or operations. It's bad writing.

Answer (score 1):

You are right not to be clear. It is the most awful management-speak. What I think it means is that a company that has succeeded in a local market may have done so through a style of leadership that is not suitable for a globalised company. Global companies need leadership on a different scale to local companies: less detailed micro-management, for example, more strategic direction with local managers given the freedom to respond to local conditions.

Modern managers frequently coin new usages of old words in the hope that they will make an impression on their colleagues.

Comment: So we can say it means something similar to adjust, right? Thanks a lot for answering.